# Reliable methods to validate clustering of text phrases?

Tags: clustering, natural-language, validation, validity

Question is in the title. I have clustered the word embeddings of text phrases, and now want to try and check whether the resulting clusters are coherent enough. I have tried methods that are standardly used for cluster validation such as SSE, silhouette scores and Dunn index but none have proven effective in this case. Any other suggestions? Would be grateful for a detailed response or a link to any other methods which may work.

Comment: Please clarify why you consider the standard methods are ineffective - e.g. are you looking for a measure they don't provide? Or do the results not seem reasonable?

Comment: @Lynn Hey, sorry, I should have clarified, the results do not match with what I'd expect. A lot of the clusters deemed coherent by these seem incoherent upon my own manual revision, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to know whether the embedding is "coherent enough". It is not very clear what you mean by that, but I presume your question is somehow: How do I measure the quality of my embedding?

And that depends on what you want to do. The clustering property of the embedding might not have anything to do with the task you want to solve. So, find a metric that evaluates your overall task, and then tune your embedding according to this metric.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes, I want to measure the quality of my clustering, specifically to check whether each individual cluster of phrases makes sense or not (i.e, each cluster has a common "theme", say one cluster talks about dogs, and another about cats, and another about both, ideally with no overlap). The metrics I have tried so far do not yield results which I think are satisfactory. I am looking for other metrics I may have missed, and would be grateful if you could suggest a few.

Comment: @aj2k1132 My main point is that I don't think that metrics for clustering are appropriate here because the isolation of clusters, which is what is mainly measured by those cluster validation metrics, should not be the priority for word embeddings, but that is, of course, just a hunch.